# Could not initialize corosync configuration API error 12

Tags: mysql, docker, replication, high-availability, corosync

Unable to initialize corosync running inside a docker container.  The `corosync-cfgtool -s` command yields the following:

```
Could not initialize corosync configuration API error 12
```

The `/etc/corosync/corosync.conf` file has the following:

```
compatibility: whitetank

totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    threads: 0
    interface {
        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 127.0.0.1
        mcastaddr: 239.255.1.1
        mcastport: 5405
        ttl: 1
    }
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: no
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
    debug: off
    timestamp: on
    logger_subsys {
        subsys: AMF
        debug: off
    }
}
```

The `/var/log/corosync.log` file shows the following:

```
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [MAIN  ] Could not set SCHED_RR at priority 99: Operation not permitted (1)
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [MAIN  ] Could not lock memory of service to avoid page faults: Cannot allocate memory (12)
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine ('1.4.6'): started and ready to provide service.
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [MAIN  ] Corosync built-in features: nss
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [MAIN  ] Successfully read main configuration file '/etc/corosync/corosync.conf'.
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [TOTEM ] Initializing transport (UDP/IP Multicast).
May 02 20:13:22 corosync [TOTEM ] Initializing transmit/receive security: libtomcrypt SOBER128/SHA1HMAC (mode 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running the following in a bash script:

```
service corosync start
service corosync status
corosync-cfgtool -s
```

Apparently it was running too quickly and not giving corosync enough time to initialize.  Changing the script to the following seems to have worked:

```
service corosync start
service corosync status
sleep 5
corosync-cfgtool -s
```

I now see the following output from `corosync-cfgtool -s`:

```
Printing ring status.
Local node ID 16777343
RING ID 0
    id  = 127.0.0.1
    status  = ring 0 active with no faults
```